# Stop Billing Type/Terms being apended to Transaction Detail for Contract Invoices

Tags: acumatica, invoice, contract

We utilize Contract Billing to maintain yearly and monthly subscription services. When doing monthly billing, we bill for the month prior, so this is setup as **Prepaid** billing type.

[image: Contract Items Prepaid Billing Type]

We have a process called **Run Contract Billing**. This process generates Invoices for the Contracts attached to Customer Locations. However, somewhere in that process, the Billing Type or the Terms Description is being prepended to the **Transaction Description** in the line item of the invoice.

[image: Invoices and Memos]

This is confusing to customers to receive on an invoice. If I received an invoice with line items starting with "Prepaid", then I would assume it has been paid and the balance is no longer outstanding. I know I can work around this using the Report Designer and removing Prepaid from `ARTran.TransDesc`, however that feels like the wrong way to fix this. I would must rather this not be prepended in the first place. Can anyone point me in the direction of where to begin finding the cause of this prepending debacle?

Comment: Looks like it could come from the CTBillEngine graph. There are some lines in there that are setting a prefix with prepaid. I have not worked with the code related to contract billing and dont know that i have a working example setup anywhere but you should be able to override this graph and capture the row insertind/ed or updating/ed events to change or remove what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Billing Type is being prepended to the AR Transaction Description in `CTBillEngine` Graph.

[image]

If you do not wish to use the Prefix , you can override `GetTransactionDescriptionWithPrefix` method of `CTBillEngine` Graph.

```cs
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.CT;

namespace PXDemoPkg
{
    public class CTBillEnginePXDemoExt : PXGraphExtension<CTBillEngine>
    {
        public delegate string GetTransactionDescriptionWithPrefixBaseInvoke(string prefix, string description);

        [PXOverride]
        public string GetTransactionDescriptionWithPrefix(string prefix, string description, 
                                                          GetTransactionDescriptionWithPrefixBaseInvoke BaseInvoke)
        {
            return description;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. Though, after having found this code in my setup and reviewing the logic in the original source, I believe a more appropriate solution to my problem would be renaming the Billing Types of **Prepaid** and **Postpaid** to be **Prepayment** and **Postpayment**, respectively. I will talk with my team to see if they agree seeing **Prepayment** at the beginning of the transaction detail lines on the Invoice will be less confusing to our customers and accurately identify these lines are prepayments for services.